# PHP JSON with string keys

Tags: php, json

My current PHP code is:

```
<?php
//$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "select * from SocietyDatabase WHERE Name='Badminton'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$json['info'][]=$row;
}
}
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Resulting in this:

```
{"info":[["SOC003","Badminton","Sport","Me","You","me@gmail.com","badminton society"]]}
```

But I would like it in this format with the 'titles':

```
{"earthquakes": [
{
"eqid": "c0001xgp",
"magnitude": 8.8,
"lng": 142.369,
"src": "us",
"datetime": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
"depth": 24.4,
"lat": 38.322
}
]}
```

So how can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: all mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `mysql_fetch_row` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`. The latter will populate $row with column array keys whilst the prior will just provide numerical indexes.

Comment: Perfect, I knew it would be something that simple. Green tick and an upvote for you, sir

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
```

to

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PDO` for this as the old way of querying is already deprecated

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from SocietyDatabase WHERE Name='Badminton'");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the values of the first column */
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use fetch_assoc function as per below example

```
$sql = "select * from clients WHERE company_name ='abc'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{ 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $json['earthquakes']=$row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

: output like :

```
{"earthquakes":{"id":"7","company_name":"abc","physical_address":"abc","postal_address":"abc","contact_name":"abc","contact_position":"abc","contact_phone":"98
```